# TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: /learn react/i

Tags: reactjs, github-actions, github-pages

✕ renders learn react link (36 ms)

● renders learn react link

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: /learn react/i. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div
        class="sc-bczRLJ jlIjgm"
      >
        navbar
      </div>
      <button
        class="sc-gsnTZi bVnXBy"
      >
        Normal Button
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

  4 | test('renders learn react link', () => {
  5 |   render(<App />);
> 6 |   const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
    |                              ^
  7 |   expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  8 | });
  9 |

  at Object.getElementError (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/config.js:40:19)
  at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:90:38
  at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:62:17
  at getByText (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:111:19)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:6:30)
  at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
  at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)
  at _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:320:7)
  at runCLI (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:173:3)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.499 s
Ran all test suites.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the same text **"learn react"** in file **App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          learn react
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and check also if you have the same (tested) string **"learn react"** among the slashes in file **App.test.js**

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  render(<App />);
  console.log(screen);
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

This error was occured for me that text inside method

> getByText()

method is missing in **App.js** component.

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou usar async await ?

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', async () => {
  await render(<App />);
  const linkElement = screen.getByText("learn react");
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```